Setup SAML in firebase

How can I setup SAML for my firebase project ? I found a document related to this problem but I'm confused how to find these information like in the image below. Is there a way to identify them in my firebase project ?


I have google provider in my firebase sign-in method but I also want SAML sign-in method in my firebase project too. How can put all sign-in methods in my code but not conflict with the old ones like in my situation right now ? Currently this is my google provider sign-in method code:
const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential( null, tokenData.access_token ); await signInWithCredential(getAuth(), credential);


I did try like in the document guided me but I'm too confused to understand where to get these information from where in my firebase project and how put another authentication code in my source code.
